# How to load ajax in jquery-dialogextend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Am trying to develop an application where user can select date and view their transaction histories in a pop up on a button clicked then an ajax will be called and return then return inside the pop. Ref: http://romb.github.io/jquery-dialogextend/example.html

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            var remoteUrl = 'send.php';
            var largeParams = {
                param1: $("#date").val()
            };
            $("#button").click(function () {
                var dialogBox = {
                    "title": "Dialog title",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 480,
                    "modal": true,
                    "resizable": true,
                    "draggable": true,
                    "dialogClass": "ui-dialog-red",
                    "open": function () {
                        var $message = $('<div>Loading...</div>');
                        $.ajax({
                            url: remoteUrl,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: largeParams,
                            context: {
                                jDialongbox: dialogRef
                            },
                            success: function (content) {
                                this.jDialongbox.setMessage(content);
                            }
                        });

                        return $message;
                    },
                    "buttons": {"Close": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }}
                };
                var moreOptions = {
                    "closable": true,
                    "maximizable": true,
                    "minimizable": true,
                    "dblclick": "collapse",
                    "minimizeLocation": "left",
                    "icons": {
                        "close": "ui-icon-close",
                        "maximize": "ui-icon-arrow-4-diag",
                        "minimize": "ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s",
                        "restore": "ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"
                    }
                };
                $("#form").dialog(dialogBox).dialogExtend(moreOptions);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Any Suggesstion will be much appreciated.

Comment: What errors do you see in your console? What is being sent and returned when `$.ajax()` is running in the Network section?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I figured it out and i fixed it already. Is working perfect just the way i wanted @Twisty